# What logical system does hindley-milner correspond to, according to the curry howard correspondence?

Tags: logic, type-theory, propositional-logic, types-and-programming-languages, curry-howard

If I understand CHC correctly, simply typed lambda calculus corresponds to propositional logic. As HM allows polymorphic definitions by let-expressions, my guess is that it would correspond to a version of propositional logic where universal quantification over variables is allowed. But as polymorphism in HM is only allowed at the top level of types (as in `forall a, b : a -> (b -> (a, b))` but not something like `Int -> (forall a : a -> b)`.

Is this correct? And how is this system more powerful thatln simply typed lambda calculus?

Comment: Top level quantifications are also seen in logic in various circumstances. But I'm not sure this particular case has a name.

Comment: @Trebor would you say that what I said is correct?